# port 22: Permission denied on raspberry 3b

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have installed **the 2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch** on raspberry 3b, and created a file named **ssh** in boot directory in SD card, then connected mac with raspberry with an Ethernet cable, I have also turned on Sharing from wifi to Ethernet on mac, but when I wanted connect with raspberry with ssh **ssh pi@192.168.2.255** it says "ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.255 port 22: Permission denied".

I have no HDMI cables, what I should do to connect using ssh without visible devices?

Comment: 192.168.2.255 sounds like a broadcast address, not likely the IP obtained by the raspberrypi. Not sure where the dhcpd logs, but you may check the IP of your Ethernet and then try to ping IP in that subnet to find it.

Comment: @KenCheung  thx, it turned out that the Ethernet cable is broken...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Ethernet cable is broken...

Sorry for this question.